# Join to only the "latest" record with t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I've got two tables. Table "B" has a one to many relationship with Table "A", which means that there will be many records in table "B" for one record in table "A".

The records in table "B" are mainly differentiated by a date, I need to produce a resultset that includes the record in table "A" joined with only the **latest** record in table "B". For illustration purpose, here's a sample schema:

```
Table A
-------
ID

Table B
-------
ID
TableAID
RowDate
```

I'm having trouble formulating the query to give me the resultset I'm looking for any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the case of two rows in table B having the same datetime, how will you define the single latest record?  It is worth noting that DateTime is only good to 3ms (or something like that) whilst DateTime2 can measure down to nanoseconds (so is more accurate).

Comment: The column to join [Table A] with [Table B] is TableAID?

Comment: Should have included this ... you can assume that there won't be duplicate datetimes, so there will always be a "latest" :-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
select a.*, bm.MaxRowDate
from (
    select TableAID, max(RowDate) as MaxRowDate
    from TableB
    group by TableAID
) bm
inner join TableA a on bm.TableAID = a.ID
```

If you need more columns from TableB, do this:

```
select a.*, b.* --use explicit columns rather than * here
from (
    select TableAID, max(RowDate) as MaxRowDate
    from TableB
    group by TableAID
) bm
inner join TableB b on bm.TableAID = b.TableAID
    and bm.MaxRowDate = b.RowDate
inner join TableA a on bm.TableAID = a.ID
```

Comment: This does not quite answer the question fully as it only gets max row date from table b.  The question has asked for the most recent row - so rest of table b needs to be returned for that row and also needs to take into account Table B having two entries of the same date/time for a TableA reference

Comment: @Paul: I assumed TableB only has specified fields by OP. Have modified query to handle the case you mention. Duplicates may or may not be an issue for the user's data.

Comment: Just curious ... why the avoidance of "*"? what are the draw backs to using it if I really want all of the columns in the resultset anyways?

Comment: @Joel: avoiding * solves problems of: duplicate columns, assumptions about returned column order, performance penalty of selecting more data than you need, the list goes on.

Answer (score 46):

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM tableB B
             WHERE A.ID = B.TableAID
             ORDER BY B.RowDate DESC) as B
```

Comment: outer apply is much quicker !

Comment: That outer apply is blazing fast compared to other approaches I tried on my system.

Comment: I just tested the accepted answer vs this answer and I found that the outer apply was ~2 times slower than the accepted answer!

Comment: @Maderas You ran them both more than once during the testing, right?  Otherwise, the data could have been cached.

Comment: @DanielLorenz I don't remember. I usually run them a minimum of 5 times each. I also tend to restart my dev servers before I test something new to find out how well it performs, but... i don't remember.

Answer (score 3):

```
With ABDateMap AS (
    SELECT Max(RowDate) AS LastDate, TableAID FROM TableB GROUP BY TableAID
),
LatestBRow As (
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID, TableAID FROM ABDateMap INNER JOIN TableB ON b.TableAID=a.ID AND b.RowDate = LastDate GROUP BY TableAID
)
SELECT columns
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN LatestBRow m ON m.TableAID=a.ID
INNER JOIN TableB b on b.ID = m.ID
```

Answer (score 3):

table B join is optional: it depends if there are other columns you want

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tableA A
    JOIN
    tableB B ON A.ID = B.TableAID
    JOIN
    (
    SELECT Max(RowDate) AS MaxRowDate, TableAID
    FROM tableB
    GROUP BY TableAID
    ) foo ON B.TableAID = foo.TableAID AND B.RowDate= foo.MaxRowDate
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the clarity's sake and to benefit those who will stumble upon this ancient question. The accepted answer would return duplicate rows if there are duplicate `RowDate` in `Table B`. A safer and more efficient way would be to utilize `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
Select a.*, b.* -- Use explicit column list rather than * here
From [Table A] a
Inner Join ( -- Use Left Join if the records missing from Table B are still required
    Select *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TableAID ORDER BY RowDate DESC) As _RowNum
    From [Table B]
) b
On b.TableAID = a.ID
Where b._RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
    BEGIN

DECLARE @TB1 AS TABLE (ID INT, NAME VARCHAR(30) )
DECLARE @TB2 AS TABLE (ID INT, ID_TB1 INT, PRICE DECIMAL(18,2))

INSERT INTO @TB1 (ID, NAME) VALUES (1, 'PRODUCT X')
INSERT INTO @TB1 (ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'PRODUCT Y')

INSERT INTO @TB2 (ID, ID_TB1, PRICE) VALUES (1, 1, 3.99)
INSERT INTO @TB2 (ID, ID_TB1, PRICE) VALUES (2, 1, 4.99)
INSERT INTO @TB2 (ID, ID_TB1, PRICE) VALUES (3, 1, 5.99)

INSERT INTO @TB2 (ID, ID_TB1, PRICE) VALUES (1, 2, 0.99)
INSERT INTO @TB2 (ID, ID_TB1, PRICE) VALUES (2, 2, 1.99)
INSERT INTO @TB2 (ID, ID_TB1, PRICE) VALUES (3, 2, 2.99)


SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, B.PRICE
  FROM @TB1 A
  INNER JOIN @TB2 B ON A.ID = B.ID_TB1 AND B.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @TB2 WHERE ID_TB1 = A.ID)


END
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch the latest record with JOIN. I think this will help someone

```
SELECT cmp.*, lr_entry.lr_no FROM 
(SELECT * FROM lr_entry ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) 
lr_entry JOIN companies as cmp ON cmp.id = lr_entry.company_id
```