# Join with DateTime and Latest Value from another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a small database with the data from weather parameters being recorded daily.  This is a Microsoft SQL Server 2008  express Database

My tables are as follows:

```
station (id, name, position)
reading (station_id, timestamp, value) 
--station_id is the foreign key to id in station table
```

I want to Join them and get the result as below:

```
id      | name    | value  | time
--------+---------+-------------------------
0       | lake    | 73     |2013/08/16 02:00
1       | pier    | 72     |2013/08/16 02:00
2       | gate    | 81     |2013/08/16 02:00
```

Looking at question like [Join to only the "latest" record with t-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462821/join-to-only-the-latest-record-with-t-sql), I've been only able to get one row from the first table, and using [Join two tables, only use latest value of right table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502213/join-two-tables-only-use-latest-value-of-right-table), I've been able to get only the max time from second table.

How can I get the output that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with a subquery

```
SELECT  s.id,
        s.name,
        r.value,
        r.timestamp

FROM    station as s
        INNER JOIN reading as r
        on s.id = r.station_id

WHERE   r.timestamp = (

    SELECT max(timestamp)
    FROM reading
    where reading.station_id = s.station_id

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT STATION.ID,STATION.Name,T2.timestamp,T2.Value

FROM STATION
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT station_id,timestamp, value
  FROM
  (
  SELECT station_id,timestamp, value, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY station_id ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as rn
  FROM reading
  ) as T1 
  WHERE RN=1
) as T2 on STATION.ID=T2.station_id
```

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe: Fixed. Yes should by PARTITION