# Combine tables in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm new to SSIS so please bear with me.

I need to import data from a database where the customer name and contact numbers are stored in 2 different tables with a 1 to many relationship between them. The schema I am importing to uses a single table for this data with columns for telephone number and mobile number.

In the previous database, there can be more than 1 telephone number and there can also be more than 1 mobile number. Where there is more than 1 of a type of number, I only need to import the newest number recorded by looking at the last updated timestamp for the number.

I'm trying to do this in SSIS but I'm struggling to figure out how to do this. I've tried getting the customer names and doing a lookup to get the telephone and mobile numbers but I get more than 1 line per customer if they have multiple customer telephone and mobile numbers.

Any ideas how I can resolve this?

Thanks.

Abrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not define your own tables, so ...

```
create table Customer
(
    CustID int not null,
    CustName varchar(40) not null
    primary key (CustID)
)
GO

insert Customer
select 1, 'McDonald the Farmer'
union all
select 2, 'Jack the Ripper'
union all
select 3, 'Mary the Gardner'
GO

create table Contact
(
  CustID int not null
, CType varchar(1) not null -- 'P'hone or 'M'obile
, Number varchar(20)
, Whence datetime not null default(getdate())
)
GO

create index Contact_IDX on Contact (CustID, CType, Whence)
```

Execute each insert following a line at a time to get unique datetime values

```
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (1, 'P', '111-222-3333')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (1, 'P', '111-333-5555')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (1, 'P', '111-444-7777')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (1, 'M', '112-222-3333')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (1, 'M', '112-333-5555')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (1, 'M', '112-444-7777')

insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (2, 'P', '211-222-3333')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (2, 'P', '211-333-5555')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (2, 'P', '211-444-7777')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (2, 'M', '212-222-3333')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (2, 'M', '212-333-5555')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (2, 'M', '212-444-7777')


insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (3, 'P', '311-222-3333')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (3, 'P', '311-333-5555')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (3, 'P', '311-444-7777')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (3, 'M', '312-222-3333')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (3, 'M', '312-333-5555')
insert Contact (CustID, CType, Number) values (3, 'M', '312-444-7777')
```

Now

```
select C.*, PHONE.NUMBER as PHONE, MOBILE.NUMBER as MOBILE from Customer C
outer apply (select top 1 * from Contact N
             where N.CustID = C.CustID AND N.CType = 'P'
             order by N.Whence desc) AS PHONE
outer apply (select top 1 * from Contact N
             where N.CustID = C.CustID AND N.CType = 'M'
             order by N.Whence desc) AS MOBILE
```

yields the following result

```
CustID      CustName                                 PHONE                MOBILE
----------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           McDonald the Farmer                      111-444-7777         112-444-7777
2           Jack the Ripper                          211-444-7777         212-444-7777
3           Mary the Gardner                         311-444-7777         312-444-7777
```

ADDED NOTE

Your question is almost a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462821/join-to-only-the-latest-record-with-t-sql) and probably many others, but at least you are looking up more than 1 value and potentially additional fields, so it may be at least a little unique.

Comment: Thanks for your help Gary. I ended up using a cursor to go through each customer and get the telephone and mobile number. I understand that cursor's are looked down on but as this was a one off export for data migration purposes I think that I can justify it.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to find the most recent telephone number:

```
SELECT CustomerID, PhoneType, PhoneNumber
FROM ContactNumbers N
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT CustomerID, PhoneType, MAX(RecordDate) RecordDate
FROM ContactNumbers
GROUP BY CustomerID, PhoneType
) L
ON  L.CustomerID = N.CustomerID
AND L.PhoneType = N.PhoneType
AND L.RecordDate = N.RecordDate
```

Note I have guessed your table name and columns. From here you should:

1. Post your table definitions
2. Get the above SQL working in your source system